# SaveChangesAsync not working inside Azure webjob

Tags: azure, async-await, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure job which asynchronously saves records to the database. I am finding that it does not actually save anything to the database. I am definitely using async/awaits everywhere. I am adding parent (market) and child records. My database has referential constraints so the parent has to exist before the child, but that should be fine as I am doing them in the right order. I have no try-catches around my methods and there is nothing in the azure logs so it appears the job is succeeding. I have called Method1 with an await from a Winforms exe and it works fine from that. What can be wrong?

```
    public static async Task MyJob([TimerTrigger("00:02:00", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {
        await Jobs.Method1(Client, Logger);
    }


    public static async Task Method1(IClient client, ILogger logger)
    {
    await DataRepository.AddMarket(event.Id, event.MarketId);
        await DataRepository.AddMarketChild(event.MarketId, 999);
     }


    public static async Task<Market> AddMarket(string eventId, string marketId)
    {
        using (var ctx = BTBEntities.CreateContext())
        {
            var market = new Market()
            {
                MarketId = marketId,
                EventId = eventId,
            };
            ctx.Markets.Add(market);
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            return market;
        }
    }

   public static async Task<HorseBet> AddHorseBet(string marketId, long selectionId)
    {
        using (var ctx = BTBEntities.CreateContext())
        {
            var bet = new MarketChild()
            {
                MarketId = marketId,
                SelectionId = selectionId,
            };
            ctx.MarketChilds.Add(bet);
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            return bet;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a database problem it was just being swallowed by Azure. This is how I fixed it.

```
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);                
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't say something was being swallowed if there was no error handling and no logging. Where did you expect to see the error?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos normally unhandled runtime errors appear in the web job output for the instance it ran, which you can see in the Azure portal

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the environtment is going to log any unhandled exceptions. You should use proper exception handling and logging, and log the *entire* exception, not just `ex.Message`. `Exception.ToString()` returns the call stack as well, which shows you exactly where the error occurred. Many times, it's not where you thought it was